# unable to push the vagrant image to atlas

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, atlas

I have used the `ubuntu/trusty64` image for creating the vm. I added few installation and now I want to store the new image in the atlas public account. But I am not able to push the image to atlas. I tried the `vagrant push` but I am getting following error message.

```
subh@ubuntu_14$ vagrant push atlas
error archiving: No VCS found for path: /Users/subh/subh_mac/vagrant/ubuntu_14
```

My push scheme is following in VagrantFile :

```
config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
     push.app = "subh/ovs_docker"  # this box does not exist in my atlas account
end
```

Please let me know, how could I push the image to my Atlas account using `vagrant push`.

Answer (score 4):

did you ensure that you have the repo initialized within git, and have performed one commit?

An example, which would add all the files to the repo, then commit the files to your newly initialized repo.

```
git init
git add *
git commit -am "new init, first commit, vagrant"
vagrant push
```

Comment: Where would it push the vagrant image, I tried to see `git remote -v` but that is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Within your vagrantfile, you should specify where the push will go...

```
For example:
 config.push.define "ftp" do |push|
  push.host = "ftp.company.com"
  push.username = "username"
  push.password = "mypassword"
end
```

Comment: could you please tell me the changes, If I want to add the vagrant image to git.